# Sublime Text 2 - working with remote host

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

At the moment all my projects are on localhost. Is there some way, via plugin or sublime itself, to work with files on remote host, or some kind of tutorial that shows how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean via FTP? If so, have you looked at Will Bond's [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) plugin? It costs $16, but from what I've heard, it's the best available option for working with remote servers.

Comment: +1 for the above-mentioned plugin. For the time I've been using it, it's really really nice.

Comment: Does it require persistent internet connection? 

Right now I use vim on remote server after sshing. Problems with persistent internet connectivity in my area makes the current option suck pretty much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I prefer to mount the remote directory using [`sshfs`](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) and work there, otherwise I use [ST2 SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) package mentioned above.

sshfs:

> This is a filesystem client based on the SSH File Transfer Protocol. Since most SSH servers already support this protocol it is very easy to set up: i.e. on the server side there's nothing to do.  On the client side mounting the filesystem is as easy as logging into the server with ssh.

Example:

```
sshfs user@host.com:/server/path /local/path
```

Comment: the only problem with this solution is performance is very laggy.. seems like all the small IO lags it. Anyone know how to get editing over SSHFS to operate smoothly?

Comment: @Prefix That's going to happen.  Want to avoid it? Do the operations locally in a git repository and `git push` remotely